# Javascript - Getting button tag value for ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Basically what I have is a lot of  `<a>` tags which are queried from a database. They are displayed and when a user clicks on one of the tags then it fires an ajax function. Right now one button does the work of all the buttons.

The tags look like this:

```
<a  value='<?php echo $setit ?>' class='button' setdata='<?php echo 
$setit ?>'><?php echo $setit ?></a>
```

And the ajax function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(event){     
        var data1=$(this).data('setdata');
        $.ajax({
            url: "set_freq.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"set_freq":data1}, 
            success: function(data){
                data = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I'm thinking that I need to make the button id-s unique so the function can only get the correct button value. Am I on the right track? How can it be done?

Comment: Yess ids have yo be unique. Second, you can just use `$(".botton")` since your setting the class on the link

Comment: You've set the class as `button`, but you're using a `$("#button")` selector

Comment: Yes @Michael, just change selector of jquery, you need to change `$('.botton')` instead of `$('#button')`. If you are using `id` then it will take only first `id` of your page

Comment: If you have it enabled, you can shorten your <?php echo _value_ ?> to <?= _value_ ?> using PHP shorttags

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make the ids of your buttons unique. You could simply use

```
$('.button').click(function(e) {/*ajax*/});
```

to query all buttons. Note that you have to query using a `.` (for class names) instead of a `#` (for ids). Inside of the function `$(this)` will always refer to the link that was clicked.

On the other hand your id's should be unique. If you do not mind that they change on every refresh, you might use [uniqueid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php):

```
<a id="<?= uniqueid(); ?>" ... >
```

Else your database should have an unique index that you might use. But i think there is no reason to set an id at all since your JavaScript is fine without.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#button")` targets an element with `id="button"` but you certainly want to target element with `class="button"` as seen in your HTML... So you should replace the # with a dot, just like in CSS. `$(".button")`

Also, you do not need to use ID for this, even if you have multiple buttons, the eventHandler receives this as the target element, so you'll always have access to the "current" data.

Answer (score 0):

Also I think you have wrong format for data property.
The right is here:

```
<a  value='<?= $setit ?>' class='button' data-set='<?= $setit ?>'><?= $setit ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `a` tag as follows.

```
<a class='button' data-setdata='<?php echo $setit ?>'><?php echo $setit ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your tag :

```
<a  value='<?php echo $setit ?>' class='button' setdata='<?php echo 
$setit ?>'><?php echo $setit ?></a>
```

To:

```
<a class='button' id='setit'><?php echo $setit ?></a>
```

and replace your ajax function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(event){     
        var data1=$(this).data('setdata');
        $.ajax({
            url: "set_freq.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"set_freq":data1}, 
            success: function(data){
                data = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

To :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(event){    
        var data1 = document.getElementById("setit").innerHTML
      $.ajax({
            url: "set_freq.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"set_freq":data1}, 
            success: function(data){
                data = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```